# "exponential something" : what is the name of that asymptotic exponential function?

Tags: functions, exponential-function

I'm wondering if there is an precise and clearly defined name for that kind of function :

$$ f(x) = A \cdot (1-e^{-\frac{x}{\tau}}) $$

It is an "exponential something", but definitely not an exponential decay, for sure, and not an exponential growth either, because it has an asymptotic behavior ... so what is his name ?

[image]

Comment: Since its graph is congruent (in the geometric sense) --- via only reflections and shifts, in fact -- of $y = b^x,$ I doubt there is a special designated name beyond that of a basic exponential type curve.

Comment: I'd say it strongly resembles the upper half of a logistic curve: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function

Comment: In control this sort of function is typically called a "first order response". I do not know a more general name however.

Comment: In probability, $1-e^{-x/\tau}$ corresponds to the [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) of a random variable (say) $X$ that follows an [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) with parameter $1/\tau$. In particular, the expected value of $X$ would be $\tau$.